# How to show that the following set $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{T}$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness, riemann-surfaces, quotient-spaces

Let $w_1, w_2$ be two complex numbers that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e., $\frac{w_1}{w_2}$ does not belong to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\mathbb{T}= \mathbb{Z} w_1+ \mathbb{Z}w_2$.

We define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{C}$ by saying that two complex numbers $z_1, z_2$ are equivalent if and only if $z_1-z_2 \in \mathbb{T}$.

Let $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{T}$ be the set of all equivalence classes of the equivalence relation defined above.

Let $\pi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{T}$ be the canonical projection.

We define a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{T}$ by saying that a subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{T}$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

How to prove that $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{T}$ with the topology $\tau$ defined above is compact?

Comment: Your notation $\mathbb T$ is strange: $\mathbb T$ often means "torus" or other circular things (like the unit circle).  One way to see a quotient space is compact is to find a *compact set of representatives*: find a compact set $X \subset \mathbb C$ that maps onto $\mathbb C/\mathbb T$.  Then the standard mapping $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C/\mathbb T$, which is continuous, restricts to the mapping $X \to \mathbb C/\mathbb T$, and this is continuous and surjective, so the image $\mathbb C/\mathbb T$ is compact. In a similar way, $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is compact since $[0,1]$ is compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the subset
$$D = \{a w_1 + b w_2 \mid (a,b) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]\} \subset \mathbb C
$$
Clearly $D$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and so is compact. Also, the restriction of $\pi : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C / \mathbb T$ to the subset $D$ is surjective, because every equivalence class contains an element of $D$. To see why this is true, start with an arbitrary element of $\mathbb C$, written in the form $x w_1 + y w_2 \in \mathbb C$ (where $x,y \in \mathbb R$). Take $a = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $b = y - \lfloor y \rfloor$, where $\lfloor t \rfloor$ is the largest integer $\le t$. It follows that $a w_1 + b w_2 \in D$, and that $a w_1 + b w_2$ is equivalent to $x w_1 + y w_2$, because
$$(x w_1 + y w_2) - (a w_1 + b w_2) = \lfloor x \rfloor w_1 + \lfloor y \rfloor w_2 \in \mathbb Z w_1 + \mathbb Z w_2
$$
Therefore, $\mathbb C / \mathbb T$ is the continuous image of the compact set $D$, hence is compact.

Comment: Which set does the element $xw_1+yw_2$ belong to? Is $b$ taken correctly? I didn't get the idea that every equivalence class contains an element of the subset $D$.

Comment: $xw_1 + y w_2$ belongs to $\mathbb C$. Every element of $\mathbb C$ may be written in that form, because of the assumption that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$ (and because $\mathbb C$ is 2 dimensional over $\mathbb R$). I'll correct the formula for $b$.

Comment: So you mean that $xw_1+yw_2$ and $aw_1+bw_2$ (where $a$ is the fractional part of $x$ and $b$ is the fractional part of $y$) are equivalent and the last one belongs to the subest $D$.

Comment: Yes. I added a few details.

Comment: That is perfect, Thanks.